# Deploying Solr in a linux server

Tags: linux, deployment, solr

Hi all I have some issues with my solr when deploying in an linux server.

I have cd to the bin folder as usual in the linux server and typed the command solr start. But I received an error.

/var/www/html/solr-6.3.0/bin$ solr start
bash: solr: command not found

May I know how do i resolve it ? the server has java installed alrdy.

Comment: any simple google search will tell you how to invoke a application in linux . its nothing special for the solr. Unlike windows you have to add ./ for executing any command or application even if you are in the directory

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
./solr start
```

OR

from solr home directory where u see bin folder, hit this

```
bin/solr start
```

Comment: Both returns me the following error. But isn't the both commands the same as they will go into the bin and do solr start?

    
    /var/www/html/solr-6.3.0$ bin/solr start
    -bash: line 94: bin/solr: Permission denied

Comment: this may be Permission problem，so  you should check your current user's Permission